# sending image as a message to receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, action, send

I am working on a Chatting application.I has successfully send text as a message to receiver, now i want to send image as a message either by capturing or selecting from the gallery. 
I had gone through some of approaches like ACTION_SEND of Intent class. But find hard to implement it. I Had made separate class for those things which has to be send or receive.

```
public class ChatMessage {
    private String messagetext;
    private String messageuser;
    private long messagetime;
    ImageView iv;

    public ChatMessage(String messagetext, String messageuser) {
        this.messagetext = messagetext;
        this.messageuser = messageuser;
        messagetime= new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage() {

    }

    public String getMessagetext() {
        return messagetext;
    }

    public void setMessagetext(String messagetext) {
        this.messagetext = messagetext;
    }

    public String getMessageuser() {
        return messageuser;
    }

    public void setMessageuser(String messageuser) {
        this.messageuser = messageuser;
    }

    public long getMessagetime() {
        return messagetime;
    }

    public void setMessagetime(long messagetime) {
        this.messagetime = messagetime;
    }

}
```

and i populate these via following method:

```
private void displayChatMessage(){
    final ListView listofmessage= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.list_item,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            TextView messagetext,messaggeuser,messagetime;
            messagetext=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            messaggeuser=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messagetime=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            messagetext.setText(model.getMessagetext());
            messaggeuser.setText(model.getMessageuser());
            messagetime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessagetime()));

        }
    };
    listofmessage.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

so, please suggest some approaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a custom dialog or pop-up window to make the user choose whether he wants to capture an image with the camera or he want to select one from the gallery, Then you need to dispatch the right intent depend on what he will choose so if he chooses to capture and image from the gallery this will be your intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), yourRequestCode);
```

Your request code is simply an int you can distinguish with later when a result comes that it was the response for this intent action.
if the user chooses to snap a picture with the camera this is how your intent will be like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, antherRequestCode);
```

then after he successfully grab a picture from the gallery or snap one with the camera `onActivityResult` method will be invoked with the returned image, and there where you should handle what you are going to do with that image so first you ovride the method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE:

                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                Log.e("ImageUri", imageUri != null ? imageUri.toString() : "Empty Uri");

                break;
            case TAKE_IMAGE_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE:
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                Log.e("ImageUri", extras != null ? imageBitmap.toString() : "no Bitmap found");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

So as you can see from the code above the gallery intent returns the image Uri and the camera intent return a bitmap and now that you have the image you can encoded to base64 or turn it to a byte array or adding it to a file and send it to the desired reciever.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but how to find uri of selected image from gallery?

Comment: as I described  in the code of the onActivityResult method in the switch statement case the the requestCode equals the requestCode that you provided when you triggered the intent then you call  the getData() method on the returned intent as data.getData() to get the Uri.